# How to Store and Edit Data from Index.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, visual-studio-2015

I have a model with 4 fields:

```
    public string facility { get; set; }
    public string hub{ get; set; }
    public double customerCount { get; set; }
    public double cmtsValue { get; set; }
```

the cmtsValue is the customercount divided by the sum of each customerCount which is shown here:

```
        @{     
                double totalValues = Model.Sum(c => c.customerCount);
                double cmtsValue = (item.customerCount / (totalValues * 1.0));
                @Html.Raw(cmtsValue.ToString("0.##%"))
        }
```

This formula is done in the Index.cshtml using Razor Code. In the View it shows up correctly but in the database its still stored as 0,
how can I save changes or edit values straight from the index.cshtml? I tried using the approach from Create.cshtml and Edit.cshtml but I am having no luck

EDIT: What I have tried doing is adding a method in my ViewController:

```
    public void SaveCMTSValue(int? id, double totalValues, double cmtsValue)
    {
        FacilityEditor facilityEditor = db.FacilityEditor.Find(id);
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            facilityEditor.cmtsValue = cmtsValue;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

then in my Index.cshtml is the following code:

```
        @{


            double totalValues = Model.Sum(c => c.customerCount);
            double cmtsValue = (item.customerCount / (totalValues * 1.0));
                @Html.Raw(cmtsValue.ToString("0.##%"))


            @Html.ActionLink("SaveCMTSValue", "SaveCMTSValue", "FacilityEditor", new { id = item.ID, totalValues = totalValues, cmtsValue = cmtsValue })

        }
```

But I'm just getting an error, whats a substitute for an actionlink if I want the data to be added automatically.

Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: What have you tried ? Show us the code you tried to save this data to your db table.

Comment: @Shyju I added the changes to my post

Comment: You should add the relevant code to the original question

Comment: @Shyju just did, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of `Html.ActionLink` method.

Use this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("SaveCMTSValue", "SaveCMTSValue", "FacilityEditor"
            , new { id = item.ID, totalValues = totalValues, cmtsValue = cmtsValue }
            , new { id="saveCmt"})
```

This will generate a link and clicking on the link with the query string values which matches your action method parameter names so model binding will work.

Now when user clicks on the link it will be a GET request to the SaveCMTSValue action method with the id, totalValues and cmtsValues in the querystring. That means anyone can try to access the url and pass whatever the data you want in the querystring parameter and your code will save that to the db table.

Generally it is a good idea to use an HttpPost action to update the db table values. So i suggest you to convert your action method to HttpPost type.

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveCMTSValue(int? id, double totalValues, double cmtsValue)
{
      // save
}
```

Now clicking on the link usually issue a GET request. To make this work with HttpPost, we need to catch the click event on this link, and issue an HttpPost call using ajax.

```
$(function(){

  $("#saveCmt").cilck(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.post($(this).attr("href"),function(res){
        alert("Updated");
     });
  });

});
```

I also suggest you just use the **id** and get the data again and do your calculation and generate the value again in your action method and use that value to save.

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveCMTSValue(int? id)
{
  // with id, get the releavnt data, generate the value and save
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help, your original answer worked for me, but quick question, if I want the data to be updated automatically instead of a link being produced, how would I be able to do so?

Comment: you need to define automatic.  When your original page loads ?  Then you can do the same code (to save to db) in your GET action method which renders your page.

Comment: by automatic, I mean, when I create the object or when editing and I click submit, it will update the value in the db.

Comment: Sure. If you have an action method which handles the edit form submit, you can do this there as well. But from your original question title, i thought you wanted to do it from the index view itself ( without a form submit). Hence suggested the ajax form submit.

Comment: sorry let me be more specific, When the object is created or edited and returns back to the index.cshtml view. I want a method to be automatically called in that view, that does those calculations and stores it in the models db.

Comment: As I explained in my previous comment, you may do that in your http post action method before redirecting to your view get action method. There is no need to do a database update in a get views view.